# NLP text distances

Tags: nlp

what is best way to calculate distance between words for semantic meaning. For example.. assume we are searching for word "fraud" in documented associated with 2 nouns - "person A"  and "person B". Text is something like below.
......"PersonA".....fraud.............."PersonB".........................................................................."fraud"
conslusion in "Noun - "PersonA is more likely to be adjective "fraud" since "fraud" is nearer to "PersonA" than "PersonB". Is there any good algorithm/statistical model to measure this for "text mining"

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it seems that the measure you're trying to obtain isn't an ordinary 'semantic meaning' distance, or [semantic similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity). It's more likely to be [association measure](http://clic.cimec.unitn.it/marco/teaching/compling/materials/ams-ho.pdf).

So, if you have a lot of occurrences of words to be processed, then look at [PMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information) or other distributional similarities (e.g. 8 week lectures of [Natural Language Processing course](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture)).

If you have just several occurrences, then I'd suggest to perform syntax parsing and measure ordinary distance in parse tree.

Comment: Thanks. Please take similar example and explain "association measure"

Comment: I don't understand what examples do you mean. In any case, look at this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(statistics)

Comment: how to measure using parse tree? Is the parse tree - one built after POS tagging?

Comment: Find the path between tree nodes corresponding to your words and count the length of the path (in edges). No, it is a tree after syntax parsing, e.g. in NLTK: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html